# How to receive a CAN frame sent in python which uses a CANard library?

Tags: python

I am working with the CANtact toolkit to send and receive can frame I used the following code which was written by Eric Evenchick founder of CANtact toolkit. All the lines of code get executed without any error but when I give `frame=dev.recv()`the cursor moves to the next line and does not show any result where could I find the result or Am i committing any mistake?
I have attached a screenshot of my terminal.

```
from canard import can
from canard.hw import socketcan
dev = socketcan.SocketCanDev("slcan0") #slcan0 refers to the CANtact kit i have connected
dev.start()
frame = can.Frame(id=0x100)
frame.dlc = 8
frame.data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
dev.send(frame)
frame = dev.recv()
print(frame)
```

[image: screenshot of the program executed in python3]
[image: using two devices]

Answer (score 0):

By default, CAN sockets don't receive the frames they send themselves. It makes little sense anyway. There are two cases that make sense:

- The code as you have it, but with another device/process connected on the bus that will *react* to the message you send, so the `dev.recv()` receives that reaction.
- Have two processes, one doing the `dev.send()` and another doing the `dev.recv()`. The later should start first, so it is already listening when the frame is sent (processes do see frames sent from the same device they run on, just not the ones they send themselves).

Comment: will I be able to see the message if i use two devices one to send and another to receive the message?

Comment: I am able to see the message with a single device. I sent the frame in one terminal and received the frame in another terminal using a single CANtact tool named as slcan0. But if I use two devices again I am not able to view the message I sent the frame in one CANtact tool named as slcan0 and I tried to receive the frame in another CANtact tool named as slcan1 and connected both the CANtact toolkits with DB9 female to DB9 female cable but I am not able to view the message. How can I send and Receive frames with two different devices I have attached a screenshot for reference

Comment: @annonymous, please, make that a *separate question*; changing the questions does not work well on this site. When you do that, make sure you include a photo of the setup, because this next problem might well be in not having connection between the elements you thought you have.

Comment: @annonymous [DE9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature#DE-9)